# How to load a YAML file with swagger-ui-express?

Tags: node.js, swagger

I have following problem - i am using swagger-ui-express and when i am not on developement env i am facing parsing issue with my swagger;

```
{"message":"Parsing swagger document failed. SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"}
```

This is in my swagger.js:

```
const {developmentEnv} = config;
    const swaggerFile = developmentEnv
        ? jsYaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync('./src/api/swagger.yml'))
        : require('../../api/swagger.yml');
```

I think, problem is with **require**. Yaml seems to be problem here. Can anybody help me with this please?

Comment: See https://bryanavery.co.uk/swagger-ui-reading-yaml-file/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is with requiring .yaml file.

The documentation clearly says,

> To load your swagger specification yaml file you need to use a module
> able to convert yaml to json; for instance yamljs.

Here is the link https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-express#load-swagger-from-yaml-file

For example, Try this, it works:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const pathToSwaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-dist').absolutePath();
const YAML = require('yamljs');

const swaggerDocument = YAML.load('swagger-config.yaml');
console.log(swaggerDocument);

const swaggerJsonDocument = require('./swagger.json');
console.log(swaggerJsonDocument);

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(pathToSwaggerUi))
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../views')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`Hello World!`);
});
app.listen(2000, console.log(`App Listening to port 2000`));
```

In your case, you could write the code like below by importing a module **yamljs**:

First of all do, **npm install yamljs**

```
   const swaggerFile = developmentEnv ? YAML.load('swagger-config.yaml') : require('./swagger.json');
```